# I/O Error: Socket closed

Tags: java, hibernate

I've found the following error in my application's error log file.

"ERROR [org.sample.dao.hibernate.LoginDAOImpl] org.sample.dao.hibernate.LogonDAOImpl -
 Exception Catched in [getHostIdFromDB] method : - IO Error: Socket closed"

The following is a snippet of getting a value from the database.

```
try {
    session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
    conn = session.connection();
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute("select GLOBAL_VAR.FN_GET_HOST from dual");
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    rs.next();
    sysdate = (String) rs.getObject(1);
    log.debug(this.getClass().getName() + " - [getHostIdFromDB] - Exit");
    return sysdate;
    } catch (Exception exp) {
      log.error(this.getClass().getName() + " - Exception caught in [getHostIdFromDB] "
                    + exp.getMessage());
    }
```

---

As this error is logged once in the error log file I can guess this could be some network connection problem. But I want to know more about this error(IO Error: Socket closed") and it's root cause. Any clarifications would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection time out could be because of a Driver/DB issue or because the result is too long to be read or the query is taking lot of time to execute . Try moving to a pooled connection C3p0 and see if you get better results .